# (MDX) how to use current member name as another column?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap

Example MDX query from https://quartetfs.com/resource-center/mdx-query-basics:

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[ASIN].[ASIN].Members} ON ROWS,
NON EMPTY {[Category].[Category].[LCD]} ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Amazon] 
WHERE ( [Measures].[Gross.Profit], 
        [Time].[ALL].[AllMember].[2011].[5], 
        [Brand].[Brand].[LG])
```

[image: results table]

---

How could one repeat the `ASIN` field (pink column) in another column?

I tried adding `[ASIN].[ASIN]` to `ON COLUMNS` expression

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[ASIN].[ASIN].Members} ON ROWS,
NON EMPTY {[Category].[Category].[LCD],[ASIN].[ASIN]} ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Amazon] 
WHERE ( [Measures].[Gross.Profit], 
        [Time].[ALL].[AllMember].[2011].[5],
        [Brand].[Brand].[LG])
```

Which resulted in `Two sets specified in the  function have different dimensionality.` Adding `.CurrentMember` resulted in the same error.

I tried adding ASIN property through new measure:

```
MEMBER Measures.ASIN AS [ASIN].[ASIN].CurrentMember
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[ASIN].[ASIN].Members} ON ROWS,
NON EMPTY {[Category].[Category].[LCD],Measures.ASIN} ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Amazon] 
WHERE ( [Measures].[Gross.Profit],
        [Time].[ALL].[AllMember].[2011].[5], 
        [Brand].[Brand].[LG])
```

Which adds a new column with `null` values.

---

What I want to see is:

<kbd>______________</kbd><kbd>LCD________</kbd><kbd>ASIN__________</kbd>
<kbd>B003D4WAVW</kbd>      <kbd>124,420.16</kbd>      <kbd>B003D4WAVW</kbd>      
<kbd>**...**</kbd>

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
MEMBER Measures.ASIN AS [ASIN].[ASIN].CurrentMember.Member_Name
MEMBER Measures.LCD AS ([Category].[Category].[LCD],[Measures].[Gross.Profit])
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[ASIN].[ASIN].Members} ON ROWS,
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[LCD],[Measures].[ASIN]} ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Amazon] 
WHERE ( [Time].[ALL].[AllMember].[2011].[5], 
        [Brand].[Brand].[LG])
```

You tried to use dimension and measure member on the same axis. I've transformed this into two measures.

Tested on my own data:
[image: DimensionAndMeasureOnOneAxis]